# Different uses of pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers

I know * indicates it is a pointer, but what's the difference between `int (* a)[2]` and `(int (*)[2]) a` in `C`?

Comment: Compare the first and second on http://cdecl.org and you will see the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int (* a)[2];` declares `a` as *a pointer to an array of two `int`* while `(int (*)[2]) a` casts `a` to *a pointer to an array of two `int`*.